# Onsubmit event refusing to fire

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code.

```
class Validationator
{
    constructor()
    { 
        this.initValidation()
    }

    initValidation()
    {
        window.addEventListener("load", this.PerformOnLoad, false);
    }

    PerformOnLoad()
    {
        var form = document.querySelector("#feedbackcontainer");

        form.addEventListener("onsubmit", this.SubmitClicked);
    }

    SubmitClicked()
    {
        alert("asdf");
    }
}
```

I have tried using both 'submit' and 'onsubmit' and neither are working. I have verified that the query selector is grabbing the proper form. Pardon my being a beginner at Javascript. Event handlers keep defeating me.

Comment: It should be `submit`, not `onsubmit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the event doesn't include the `on` prefix -- that's only used in the corresponding attribute name.

Also, if you use a class method as a callback function, you need to bind it to the object. Otherwise, `this` in the method will be the global `window` object, not the `Validationator` object.

```
class Validationator
{
    constructor()
    { 
        this.initValidation()
    }

    initValidation()
    {
        window.addEventListener("load", this.PerformOnLoad.bind(this), false);
    }

    PerformOnLoad()
    {
        var form = document.querySelector("#feedbackcontainer");

        form.addEventListener("submit", this.SubmitClicked.bind(this));
    }

    SubmitClicked()
    {
        alert("asdf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`form.addEventListener("onsubmit", this.SubmitClicked);` onsubmit is wrong the correct is `form.addEventListener("submit", this.SubmitClicked);` and any other codes?

Answer (score 0):

At the `PerformOnLoad()` function there can not be `onsubmit` event, it would be just `submit`.

As well as, you need to use `bind` while you call the `PerformOnLoad()` and `SubmitClicked()` methods. In that case, the final code would be like,

```
class Validationator
{
    constructor()
    { 
        this.initValidation()
    }

    initValidation()
    {
        window.addEventListener("load", this.PerformOnLoad.bind(this), false);
    }

    PerformOnLoad()
    {
        var form = document.querySelector("#feedbackcontainer");

        form.addEventListener("submit", this.SubmitClicked.bind(this));
    }

    SubmitClicked()
    {
        alert("asdf");
    }
}
```